# Are there consequences to refusing to sign an agreement?

Tags: signatures, byod

I work as a public school teacher, but produce educational materials as a side gig. Note this side gig provides a mutual benefit to the school: I provide these materials for free within my school.

The district lawyers said so long as the work is done outside hours, on my own equipment, they won't claim the IP. But now they've changed their mind, asked me to sign a document saying anything on their HDDs becomes their IP. So now even though I used my own time, my own devices, they are trying to claim ownership even if a file exists on their machines. That puts a halt to me using my own IP in my own classes, sharing them  with co-workers and students, as they're also banning me from BYOD.

I've been asked to sign this in exchange for receiving the laptops which I use for grading, attendance, E-mail, etc.

Does the boss have a right to force me to sign an agreement of this type? What could be the consequence of refusing to do so?

Comment: No one has the right to force you to sign anything. If you refuse or don't agree with the terms, it's likely they could let you go. Please tell us your location to give better answers

Comment: “Does the boss have a right to force me to sign an agreement of this type?” - Can they force you to sign the agreement, I suppose they can make it difficult, but they absolutely can implement a plan that makes BYOD an impossibility.  **So do your “side gig” outside of work on your personal hardware**

Comment: Allow me to summarize: _Your job wants to provide you with laptop and as condition to using it, they would claim rights over things you produce on your own hardware, in your free time._ Is that right? Because I find that hard to believe, but if it is actually the case, it sounds like someone was being sloppy writing the agreement and it should be viable to push back and ask for modifying clause or two.

Comment: Talk to your teachers union

Comment: Not an answer, but, remove all of your IP from their devices and format the drive as a precautionary measure. If they're willing to push for your IP like this, I wouldn't put it past them to claim that it was developed on their device, and belongs to them as a result. Simplest way to protect yourself is to remove every trace of it from devices they own.

Comment: If Microsoft Word is installed on the HDD, are they trying to claim that's their IP too? They're going to have fun with that one (Microsoft has really good lawyers). You should consult a lawyer.

Comment: There’s no way to know whether there is general employment law covering this situation without a location. (Country at minimum, state might matter if you’re in the US.) But I agree with coll that your union would be most helpful if you have one.

Comment: The lesson is, never give away your work for free, you create things on your own time and device and then sell it to your employer and then it belongs to them. This mess wouldn‘t exist had you just sold it to the school. Your next step should be to remove all products produced by you, that you‘ve given away and then sign the contract and sell the products back to the school with the appropriate licensing. If they don‘t want to use it, that‘s their fault. You will also have to suffer using _only_ what the school provides.

Comment: When did teachers exactly become slave labor? Jesus, is there anything a damn school principal would not require from a teacher? Is it not enough that we work harder than most people for less than half the average salary. Now when we try to get a side hustle going so we can eat breakfast, lunch, and dinner every day we need to get hell for that too.

Answer (score 11):

> At the start of each school year, my school distributes various
> laptops and tablets to each teacher, after we sign a terms of use
> agreement. Recently the district rewrote it with very broad terms
> giving them routes to claim ownership of my IP. Never before has such
> language appeared on these agreements.

Make sure you understand the terms of the document before you sign it, and before you refuse to sign it. If necessary, run it by your attorney.

> I declined signing, explained why, and said I'd just use my own
> device, as I have for 10 years anyway. The principal told me she also
> plans to ban outside devices.

It makes sense never to use their devices for your outside work. As long as you use your own devices on your own time in your own home for your own outside work, there is nothing to ban.

They can ban you from using your own devices to do their work.

> Does the boss have a right to force me to sign an agreement of this
> type?

You can't be forced to sign anything.

> What could be the consequence of refusing to do so?

The consequences could include the loss of your job, depending on your local laws.

When in doubt, consult an attorney or other qualified legal advisor. If you are in a teacher's union, you might want to chat with your rep.

Answer (score 1):

Go straight to the source, the legal department of your school district, and communicate your willingness to sign a modified copy of the agreement. But do not ask for permission, just follow the process I'm outlining below.

Strike out the relevant clause, or add your own clause carving an exception for your existing educational business, mention the business by name, highlight the change you've made in your cover email, highlight the fact that this is an existing business, and that they've known about it for many years, and send that modified agreement back to the relevant legal department/HR.

If the agreement is on paper, do the same thing, make a photocopy, strike out the clause, initial the change, highlight the changes you've made in a cover letter, and send it back to them (but do not sign it yet).

Do not ask for permission. Just do it. And do not call them beforehand. You want to maintain a papertrail. Also, doing this will show that you're taking this seriously, but that they're the ones that are holding up the process, not you.

> Does the boss have a right to force me to sign an agreement of this
> type? What could be the consequence of refusing to do so?

If you work in "at will" state and if you don't have a union, your boss can probably do whatever she wants legally speaking.

But I don't think that's the question you should be asking. The question you should be asking is whether your principal is really willing to lose a qualified teacher over the ownership of the educational materials she created.

And if for some crazy reason, you do get fired for "insubordination", you want to make sure you do have a paper trail proving your side of the story (to the school board, or to the unemployment office).

And finally, try to figure out what's their end game here. Are they really trying to take ownership of your existing materials? Do they have something else in mind? And if they want to use your materials, would they be willing to buy a limited license for those materials?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you need to use school devices?

I think the solution is obvious - work on your IP materials on your time and machines.

No agreement should include provision that anything done by you on your own time and using your equipment can be claimed by the employer

Answer (score 0):

> The principal told me she also plans to ban outside devices.

She's bluffing, she cannot ban outside devices except on the premises. You can use whatever personal devices you want outside the workplace. It's likely she just meant banning the use of personal devices for work, which is perfectly reasonable. If the school is providing tools they have every right to expect you to use them instead of providing your own.

> sign a terms of use agreement.

This only applies to the gadget that's being signed for. So there is no reason you shouldn't sign this if you're not going to use it outside the 'terms of usage'.

Realistically not signing is just unnecessary drama bringing your side gig under a spotlight. It's more constructive to analyse why these new conditions are being put in place. Possibly there are complaints about your side gig or something else going on. Or perhaps you're totally misreading the whole situation.